# How do you Mark ASM code?

Tags: assembly, clang

I am trying to mark my ASM (generate by the compiler) to make a postpone analysis between my mark my analysis the corresponding .s file. The following MACRO works with GCC

```
#define ASM_LABEL(label) asm ("#" label "\n\t")
```

Nevertheless with CLANG the label is removed.

```
void kernel(double const * x, double * y){
    ASM_LABEL (START)
    y[0]+=x[1]+x[3]/x[4];
    y[1] = std::exp(x[0]);
    ASM_LABEL (STOP)
}
```

The generated ASM (clang -O3 -S) gives:

```
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    ## InlineAsm Start
    ## InlineAsm End <---- no START mark
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movsd   8(%rsi), %xmm0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
    ..............
```

The label has been deleted. Do you have any suggestion ? Does exist an generic tips ?

Thank you

Comment: Add `volatile`? I think you get line numbers in the generated asm anyway. Also note that optimized code might not even map to a single block of assembly...

Comment: If `gcc` semantics are being preserved, the lack of an output variable in the `asm` statement makes the statement `volatile` implicitly. (ref: [gcc extended asm documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clang will, by default, use its integrated llvm assembler, but this can be disabled with the command line option `-fno-integrated-as`.

Specifying this along with `-S` should preserve the comments from the inline asm. Running `clang -S -O3 -fno-integrated-as` on the code sample

```
#include <cmath>
#define ASM_LABEL(label) asm ("#" label "\n\t" ::: "memory");

void kernel(double const * x, double * y){
    ASM_LABEL("START")
    y[0]+=x[1]+x[3]/x[4];
    y[1] = std::exp(x[0]);
    ASM_LABEL("STOP")
}
```

Gives the assembly (leaving out directives and labels):

```
pushq   %rbx
movq    %rsi, %rbx
#APP
#START

#NO_APP
movsd   24(%rdi), %xmm0
divsd   32(%rdi), %xmm0
addsd   8(%rdi), %xmm0
addsd   (%rbx), %xmm0
movsd   %xmm0, (%rbx)
movsd   (%rdi), %xmm0
callq   exp
movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rbx)
#APP
#STOP

#NO_APP
popq    %rbx
retq
```

Comment: Oh monseigneur, you're so smart.